# pH-value of a multicomponent buffer

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph

We are trying to predict the pH-value of a multicomponent buffer. It consists of:

\begin{array}{lcrr}
\# &\text{Component} &C,\,\pu{mol L-1} &\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} &\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2} &\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a3}\\
\hline
1 &\text{Citric acid} &\pu{2.60e-5} &3.13 &4.76 &6.40 \\
2 &\ce{NaH2PO4} &\pu{5.65e-3} &7.21 & &\\   
3 &\ce{(NH4)2SO4} &\pu{2.27e-3} &9.20 & &\\   
4 &\ce{NaHCO3} &\pu{1.19e-3} &10.33 & &
\end{array}

Our problem is that we don't know how to combine several equilibria which exist in the solution. Since $\ce{NaHCO3}$, for example, is an ampholyte, it is difficult to tell if it reacts as an acid or a base.

Although this should be a somewhat common problem, we didn't find any formula or method to calculate the pH of such systems. We would be thankful for any idea!

Comment: Where did you get all this values? If it's real problem then just mix it and check pH. Still it may be homework and it seems it breaks our homework policy.

Comment: It is a real problem indeed. I already checked the pH, but I am curious though if there's a way to calculate it. We also had the idea to write an excel-sheet or a program which tells us the pH of multicomponent systems, which would be useful in the lab.

Comment: First suggestion, you are missing some pKa's, although I think the only important ones are those of H2CO3 (3.6) and H3PO4 (2.12). Then, clearly undissociated citric acid is not compatible with HCO3- or even H2PO4-. Just make then react and star from there.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I made a mistake, the pKa of H2CO3 seems to be 6.35.

Comment: Let me guess: is the pH you measured about 6.3?

Comment: It should be at about 5.4. It's a buffer which simulates saliva called "Mondelli Buffer". You can find it by googling it. My task was to increase its pH to 6.3 without changing the concentrations of the single ions to much (it's accidentally the same as you calculated for the original buffer, I guess). So I decided to put in a smaller amount of $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ (it turned out to be $2.50\cdot 10^{-3}mol/L$). 
But I would like to know, if there is also a way to calculate the pH of more complicated systems like this in advance...

Comment: @SimonPflug. I suggest you check the Medusa (or Spana, in its newest java version) software: https://www.kth.se/che/medusa/ and https://sites.google.com/site/chemdiagr/